# Symfony2 Overiding Exception

Tags: symfony

Recently, I've put the `error.html.twig`, `error404.html.twig`, `exception.html.twig` templates to the `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception` project directory to override Symfony2 error pages. In the prod environment it's working fine; in the dev environment also its overriding the default exception template, so it is very hard for debugging.

How can I get the default template working in the dev environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overriding `exception.html.twig` is a mistake as it is only available in DEV environment, and you don't want a custom exception template.

Extract from official doc:

> The debug-friendly exception pages shown to the **developer** can even be customized in the same way by creating templates such as exception.html.twig for the standard HTML exception page or exception.json.twig for the JSON exception page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I Understood the problem

Comment: And I solved this by creating custom Event Listener,
As in official doc
[How to create an Event Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html)